# Mybatis keygenerator field how to fill with id value(which is null before)?

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis, key-generator, mybatis-generator

**Mysql** database has a table(id bigint auto_increment primary key, xx), and springboot code follows:

```
@Insert({"insert into table(xx) " +
            "values (#{xx}"})
@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true, keyProperty="id", keyColumn="id")
int save(Data data);
```

We all known,  our **insert sql language** does not contail id field, when we specify **useGeneratedKeys=true, keyProperty="id"**,then we invoke **save method**, the object data return the id value(which success to insert into the database and return valid id value).

**But insert into sql** only return affected rows, why return valid data.id value?

**The distribute system how to ensure the unique id from mybatis returned if mybatis has not second query id from mysql?**

How the mybatis realize it?

**Does it query the id after insert into sql??**

So does **the insert into sql** has two request database(first is insert into, second is query id value)?